# How to make this CSS hamburger menu entirely clickable?

Tags: html, css, menu, css-shapes

I am working on a pure CSS hamburger menu icon, so far it's working great, except that the gaps between the lines are not clickable. How can I modify this code so that the entire button is clickable as opposed to just the lines?

```
<a href="#" title="Open Menu" class="menu"></a>

.menu {
    width:30px;
    height:5px;
    background-color:#000;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
}
    .menu:after, .menu:before {
        content: '';
        width: 100%;
        height:5px;
        background-color:#000;
        position:absolute;
    }
    .menu:after {
        top:10px;
        left:0;
    }
    .menu:before {
        top:20px;
        left:0;
    }
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0bf4vxmt/).

Thanks!

Comment: You could draw a white box under each black box instead of just creating white space.

Comment: You could just wrap the <a> tag around a div that has the before and after properties.  Otherwise you won't select :after properties.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just do this

**DEMO - 1** (border top or bottom)

```css
.menu {
    width:30px;
    height:20px;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    border-top:4px solid black;
}
 .menu:after, .menu:before {
     content: '';
     width: 100%;
     height:4px;
     background-color:#000;
     position:absolute;
 }
 .menu:after {
     bottom:0px;
     left:0;
 }
 .menu:before {
     top:6px;
     left:0;
 }
```

```html
<a href="#" title="Open Menu" class="menu"></a>
```

**DEMO -2** (box-shadow)

```css
.menu {
    width:30px;
    height:20px;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    box-shadow:inset 0 4px 0 black;
}
 .menu:after, .menu:before {
     content: '';
     width: 100%;
     height:4px;
     background-color:#000;
     position:absolute;
 }
 .menu:after {
     bottom:0px;
     left:0;
 }
 .menu:before {
     top:8px;
     left:0;
 }
```

```html
<a href="#" title="Open Menu" class="menu"></a>
```

**DEMO - 3** (only :before or after mixed box-shadow inset)

```css
.menu {
    width:30px;
    height:20px;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    box-shadow:inset 0 4px 0 black,inset 0 -4px 0 black;
}
 .menu:after{
     content: '';
     width: 100%;
     height:4px;
     background-color:#000;
     position:absolute;
        top:8px;
     left:0;
 }
```

```html
<a href="#" title="Open Menu" class="menu"></a>
```

**DEMO - 4**

```css
.menu {
    width:30px;
    height:14px;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    border-top: 4px solid black;
    border-bottom: 4px solid black;
}
 .menu:after{
     content: '';
     width: 100%;
     height:4px;
     background-color:#000;
     position:absolute;
        top:5px;
     left:0;
 }
```

```html
<a href="#" title="Open Menu" class="menu"></a>
```

**DEMO - 5** (using background image)

```css
.menu {
width: 30px;
height: 26px;
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
background-size: 10px 10px;
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 50%, transparent 50%, transparent);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 50%, transparent 50%, transparent);
background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 50%, transparent 50%, transparent);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" title="Open Menu" class="menu"></a>
```