# Hamburger menu: how do I make the spaces between checkbox label "slices" clickable?

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I've created a CSS-only hamburger menu using the [CSS Checkbox Label Hack](https://www.google.com/search?q=css%20checkbox%20label%20hack). Works great except...the gaps between the "slices" of the hamburger aren't clickable. There's a [great post here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26150963/how-to-make-this-css-hamburger-menu-entirely-clickable) that addresses that issue, but it's using an anchor tag instead of a form label, which is required by the checkbox hack. Any ideas how to make that whole area a clickable label? Here is [my code](https://codepen.io/scott8035/pen/mpZZvY):

HTML:

```
<div id="hamburger-menu-icon">
    <label id="hamburger-menu-label" for="hamburger">
        <span></span>
    </label>
    <input id="hamburger" type="checkbox"> 
    <div id="hamburger-menu-panel">
      <p>Item 1</p>
      <p>Item 2</p>
      <p>Item 3</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
$hbmLineWidth: 8px;
$hbmLineLength: 50px;

#hamburger-menu-icon {
   background-color: #399;
   position: fixed;
   top: 17px;
   left: 0;
   width: $hbmLineLength;
   height: $hbmLineWidth; 
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   cursor: pointer;

   #hamburger-menu-label {
      cursor: pointer;
      width: $hbmLineLength;
      height: $hbmLineWidth;

      span {

         width: $hbmLineLength;
         height: $hbmLineWidth;

         &::after, &::before {
            display: block;
            content: '';
            background-color: #399;
            width: $hbmLineLength;
            height: $hbmLineWidth;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
         }

         &::before {
            background-color: #f00;
            position: absolute;
            margin-top: -14px;
         }

         &::after {
            background-color: #00f;
            position: absolute;
            margin-top: 14px;
            height: $hbmLineWidth + 1;
         }
      }
   }

   #hamburger { 
      display: none; 
   } 
}

#hamburger-menu-panel {
  display: none;
  background: #aaa;
  position: fixed;
  top: 46px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;

  p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 4px 6px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  p:hover {
    background-color: #ccc;
  }
}

#hamburger:checked ~ #hamburger-menu-panel {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Why not make it a single element (no pseudos) and use a `linear-gradient` to make the hamburger icon? That way it'll look the same while being clickable, even in the gaps.

Comment: @JaKhris, I tried your technique and it works great! Thanks for the tip, and I'll post the resulting code below.

Comment: Happy to be of assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @JaKhris' suggestion, I've come up with an answer, which I [posted on Codepen](https://codepen.io/scott8035/pen/aEejrq). Here's the code:

HTML

```
<div id="hamburger-menu-icon">
    <label id="hamburger-menu-label" for="hamburger-menu-checkbox">
    </label>
    <input id="hamburger-menu-checkbox" type="checkbox"> 
    <div id="hamburger-menu-panel">
      <p>Item 1</p>
      <p>Item 2</p>
      <p>Item 3</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

SCSS

```
$hbmLineLength: 25px;

#hamburger-menu-icon {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

#hamburger-menu-label {
  display: block;
  width: $hbmLineLength;
  height: $hbmLineLength;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(
      to bottom, 
      #399 0%, #399 20%,
      #fff 20%, #fff 40%,
      #399 40%, #399 60%,
      #fff 60%, #fff 80%,
      #399 80%, #399 100%      
    );
  cursor: pointer;
}

#hamburger-menu-checkbox { 
  display: none; 
} 

#hamburger-menu-panel {
  display: none;
  background: #aaa;
  position: fixed;
  top: 31px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;

  p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 4px 6px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  p:hover {
    background-color: #ccc;
  }
}

#hamburger-menu-checkbox:checked ~ #hamburger-menu-panel {
  display: block;
}
```

Things are much easier without the pseudo-elements, and the gradient allows very precise specification of the line/gap widths.